# how can i show default toolbar(pagination) on my product page

Tags: php, magento, pagination

i want to show pagination on my product page. Please check my code,

This is my controller:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'descryption'))
        ->setPageSize(10);
$numberOfPages = $model->getLastPageNumber();
$data['products'] = $model->setCurPage($i)->load();
```

and this is my view:

```
 <div id="sectionA3" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <?php 
                                    foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
                                        $productName = $product->getName();
                                        $productImage = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" .$product->getImage();
                                ?>
                                        <div class="celeb-post" id="products-listing">
                                        <img src="<?php  echo $productImage ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                        <div class="hover-image-bg">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/heart.png"></a>
                                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/bag.png"></a>
                                            <a href="#"> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/move.png"></a>
                                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/assign.png"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;"></div>
                                        <div class="celeb-name-title ucase clearfix brand-pro-title" style="text-align:center;">
                                            <?php  
                                                if (strlen($productName) > 20) {
                                                    $prostringCut = substr($productName, 0, 20);
                                                    $productstring = substr($prostringCut, 0, strrpos($prostringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
                                                    echo $productstring;
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo $productName;
                                                }
                                            ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                <?php 


                                    }
                                ?>



                            </div>
```

How can i add pagination in the bottom of my products, per page 15 products only show. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Refer Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php file For Collection
and phtml file pls refer catalog/product/list.php file

you can get all stuff for display your product at frontend 
it may helpful to you.